# Как для двух столбцов датафрейма подтянуть данные из другого дата фрейма? При то что один из параметров это дата

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Прошу помочь, всю голову сломал!

а - это продажи с датами, b - это справочник по акциям (есть артикул и период акции, а также скидка по акции).
Задача: добавить в датафрейм "а" столбец со скидкой из "b", т.е. первым делом должны найти артикул, затем проверить попадает ли дата продажи в период акции, если да, то подтянуть скидку в "а". В примере получается, что должна была бы подтянуться в новом столбце к "а" значение скидки 20, так как все продажи попали в акцию с 1 по 10 мая.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['259-2575','259-2575','259-2575','259-2575'], 
                  'A':['2022-05-01','2022-05-04','2022-05-06','2022-05-08']})

b = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['259-2575','259-2575'], 
                  'от':['2022-05-01','2022-05-15'],
                  'до':['2022-05-10','2022-05-20'],
                  'скидка':[20,10]})
```

Вот датафрейм "а"

```
         ID           A
0  259-2575  2022-05-01
1  259-2575  2022-05-04
2  259-2575  2022-05-06
3  259-2575  2022-05-08
```

Вот датафрейм "b"

```
         ID          от          до  скидка
0  259-2575  2022-05-01  2022-05-10      20
1  259-2575  2022-05-15  2022-05-20      10
```